# Styling an android activity with html?

Tags: android, html, android-activity, styles

I am trying to add a "help" screen to my application. I inserted all of my text in, but I can't make it look how I want. Is it possible to use html to style and organize my text?

Comment: you can use android web view [web view example](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-webview-example/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can create `Html` file in `assets` and use that into `WebView`. [WebView for a HTML page display in Android app](http://blog.kerul.net/2011/07/webview-for-html-page-display-in.html) is a very good example for that.

You can also refer [Android WebView Complete Example Tutorial](http://ganeshtiwaridotcomdotnp.blogspot.in/2011/09/android-webview-complete-example.html)